# Docker compose not parsing env variables for the config file inside the container

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, docker-compose

We are trying some docker containers locally. For security purposes, user and password are used as env variables in the config file. The config file is copied as the volume in the docker-compose for one of the APIs. After docker-compose up,  inside the container, we are still seeing the variable name and not the env variable value.

Config file inside the container copied as volume:

dbconfig:

```
dbuser: ${USER}
dbpass: ${PASSWORD}
dbname: 
dbdrivername: 
tablename
```

docker-compose.yaml:

services:

```
api:
    image: ${API_IMAGE:api}:${VERSION:-latest}
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    environment:
     - "USER=${USER}"
     - "PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
        - ./conf/config.yaml:/etc/api.yaml
    command: ["-config", "/etc/api.yaml"]
```

Config.yaml:

dbconfig:

```
dbuser: ${USER}
dbpass: ${PASSWORD}
dbname: 
dbdrivername: 
tablename
```

Please help us get rid of this error as we are newly adopting docker testing

Comment: What do you expect to expand the variable references in the configuration file?  (Neither Docker nor Compose will do this on its own, it just forwards references to the container file back to the host file without changing anything.)

Comment: This is impossible to answer because the entry-point of the image is unknown (what comes before `-command /etc/api.yaml` ?). Also, you should clarify what you mean by "still seeing the variable name and not the env variable value". Is the "env variable value" the value from the api.yaml file? and where are you "seeing" it?

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed with the solution mentioned here. [How to run 2 different commands from docker-compose command:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916469/how-to-run-2-different-commands-from-docker-compose-command)
We added the sed command in the entry point script which searches for the env variable inside the config and replaces it with the value. Env variables are passed from docker-compose for the service

```
sed \ 
-e "s/USER/${USER}/g" \
 -e "s/PASSWORD/${PASSWORD}/g" \ -i /etc/api.yaml
```